# Can't click on YouTube video player's next button

Tags: vbscript, youtube

I am trying to write a VBScript that opens Internet Explorer, navigates to a YouTube video, and then press the next button (the next button is show in picture).

[image]

Here you have my code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim msg, sapi, ie, shell, firstVideo

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VisBywjQuZU"
ie.Visible = 4

waitForLoad
ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("ytp-play-button ytp-button").Item(0).Click
waitForLoad
ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("ytp-next-button ytp-button").Item(0).Click

'waits for ie to be completely loaded
Sub waitForLoad
    Do while ie.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 200
    Loop
End sub
```

As you will notice by playing the script, I am able to interact with the play/pause button without problems. But when it comes to the next button, vbs is just doing nothing.

How can I make this work?

Comment: well, that link is only visible on hover over.

Comment: mmm... so there's not a possible workaround for achieve this?

Comment: I ran your code exactly as you typed it and it worked for me. So maybe there is some issue with the timing of when it is trying to click the next button? I noticed that once when I ran it there was a ad playing and then it did not work. But another time where there was no ad it did work ok, so maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Hey you're actually right. By making ws sleep a couple of seconds, the next button can be clicked! Thanks man. Post your comment as an answer!